# Deleting a data in Database using php

Tags: php, mysql

I need to delete a data on database by using PHP code, i have written the code but there is some error message.
here is the php code(del.php):-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php

$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root','');

if ($conn->connect_error) {

die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "DELETE FROM register WHERE name='' ";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)
{
  echo "Record deleted successfully";
} else {
     echo "Error deleting record: " . $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The database name is 'selva' and the table name is 'register', in database the file names are "Name,Email,Contact,Address", i need to delete the name or email or contact . how to delete!!

Comment: this has been asked so manny times here

Comment: "but there is some error message." http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @SelvaKumar what is your error message ?

Comment: DELETE FROM `register` WHERE 1

Comment: If you want to delete either one column, use update instead. Delete will only delete the whole data row

Comment: Update your server to PHP7 and discover that mysql_* is gone. NEVER use mysql_*, instead use PDO or mysqli_*.

Answer (score 1):

> //this will delete the whole row:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "your_password"; // add your pw from the here
$dbname = "selva";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
//this will delete the whole row
$sql = "DELETE FROM register WHERE 1 ";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)
{
    echo "Record deleted successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error deleting record: " . $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

> //this will delete only the COLUMNS you set here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "your_password"; // add your pw from the here
$dbname = "selva";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql = "ALTER TABLE register DROP Name, DROP Email; DROP Contact; ";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)
{
    echo "Record deleted successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error deleting record: " . $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**hope it will help you :)**